# German characters not showing properly on csv file using php

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to generate a CSV file, which gets created perfectly except for the german characters ä,ë,ï,etc I just get the information to a $data variable and tried to use:

```
utf8_encode($data);
```

but I get weird text, here are my headers for the file:

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file1.csv\"");
```

I have tried using also iconv(); but no luck thus far.

**EDIT**

just noticed that my $data is already utf-8 so I removed the utf8_encode(); still, when I try to print it I get ?

and changed the header to:

```
 header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Do you know what encoding $data is in? What settings and encodings do you use in the program you use to open that CSV with?

Comment: I tried changing it to text/plain still getting something like "√o" instead of "ü". Also, $data should be plain text but I really am not sure since I don't get to see the DB, just query it. and I'm just opening it on the preview from OS X

Comment: ok $data is already utf-8 how would that change anything if still it isn't displayed correctly? (without reencoding it, just printing $data)

Comment: @Luis Armando: The application opening the CSV file must support the encoding therein. If it doesn't you will see "weird text". Open the CSV file with OpenOffice Calc. It offers to specify the encoding while opening with a nice preview function. That might help to debug things.

Comment: "when I try to print it" do you print the plain .cvs file with the OS' printing function or do you use another application? Or do you mean displaying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

And make sure your `$data` isn't already utf-8!

Answer (score 2):

Don't know, if this may cause the error: csv is an ascii-text file. You should use `text/csv` or at least `text/plain`. At all every `text/*`-mime-type is more useful, then `application/octet-stream`, because this defines binary data, what csv-files are obviously not.

Then if the file is *already* encoded in UTF-8, don't re-encode it

```
utf8_encode($data); // not useful, if $data is already utf-8
```

Next, add the charset to the content-type header

```
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
```

(at all)

```
header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");
```

And last but not least: Make sure, that the application, with which you want to open the file, understand utf-8 and also uses it for the file.